# Generate an Update SQL for Changing the Order of an Item?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Let say I have this table,

```
 ID         Name       Order
======== ========  =========
 1           d          1
 2           g          2
 3           b          3
 4           f          4
 5           a          5
```

Now, from my UI user can change the order by drag drop. For example, he can move an item d to to item a place. Then my table will look like,

```
 ID         Name       Order
======== ========  =========
 2           g          1
 3           b          2
 4           f          3
 1           d          4
 5           a          5
```

Can any one tell me the SQL?  I have input of ID, OldOrder and NewOrder.

Comment: I'm assuming ID is your unique identifier.  Do you need to track history of order (with OldOrder) or are you only concerned with the current order that the user wants to update 'to'?

Comment: @RayK, with one update multiple rows effected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't even need the `ID` parameter.

```
UPDATE
  yourTable
SET
  Order = (CASE WHEN     Order = @oldOrder THEN @newOrder
                WHEN @newOrder > @oldOrder THEN Order - 1
                                           ELSE Order + 1 END)
WHERE
     Order BETWEEN @oldOrder AND @newOrder
  OR Order BETWEEN @newOrder AND @oldOrder
```

- Anything above or below the original and new positions don't need to be changed.
- Everything else moves up or down one.
- Except the original item, that moves to the new position.

Comment: I have to admit that your answer's much better than my (meanwhile) deleted answer... +1 for teaching me this nice solution

Comment: @user960567 - I wouldn't consider that to be at all big, considering it updates all the necessary records, deals with moves upwards and moves downwards, and does it all in a single statement. Considering everything you're asking for, how short do you want this to be? *(I wouldn't consider any SQL query to be **big** until it reaches 20+ lines at least...)*

Comment: `UPDATE yourTable` can't change.  `SET ORDER = ` can't change.  3 parts for three corner cases `Move the item to the new position` and `move other items down if the item moved up` and `move other items up if the item moved down`.  And a `WHERE` clause to ensure you only update rows that actually need updating.

Comment: Great solution and works also with SQL Lite on Android.