# Changing the order of a Row not working?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I was using this stackoverflow trick for a long time which was working fine for a fair amount of period. [Generate an Update SQL for Changing the Order of an Item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474441/generate-an-update-sql-for-changing-the-order-of-an-item)

But if there is a record is missing between rows the it will not work. See this sample,

```
declare @MyTable table 
(
    [ID] INT,
    [Order] INT,
    Name VARCHAR(20)
)
insert into @MyTable values(11111,1,'A'), (22222,2,'B'), (3333,3,'C'),(44444,4,'D');
select * from @MyTable;
--which will gives you
    ----------------------
--  ID    Order     Name
--  11111   1        A
--  22222   2        B
--  3333    3        C
--  44444   4        D
    ----------------------

-- Now just delete a row
delete from @MyTable where [ID] = 3333;
select * from @MyTable;
--which will gives you
    --------------------
--  ID    Order     Name
--  11111   1   A
--  22222   2   B
--  44444   4   D
    --------------------
-- Now just decrement the order of 4
declare @OldOrder INT = 4;
declare @NewOrder INT = @OldOrder - 1;

UPDATE  @MyTable 
SET [Order] = (CASE 
                WHEN 
                    [Order] = @OldOrder 
                THEN 
                    @NewOrder
                WHEN 
                    @NewOrder > @OldOrder 
                THEN 
                    [Order] - 1
                ELSE 
                    [Order] + 1 
            END)
WHERE   ([Order] BETWEEN @OldOrder AND @NewOrder OR [Order] BETWEEN @NewOrder AND @OldOrder)

select * from @MyTable;
--which will gives you
--------------------
--ID    Order   Name
--11111 1   A
--22222 2   B
--44444 3   D
--------------------

--The result should be
--------------------
--ID    Order   Name
--11111 1   A
--22222 3   B
--44444 2   D
--------------------
```

Comment: What is your criteria of making `44444` as `Order No. 2` and `22222` should be on `Order No. 3`?

Comment: If you explain what the logic is, then I will update my answer with a solution...currently, I can only point out the issue.

Comment: @christiandev, just a simple table where I am assigning the order 1,2,3, so on. Now user can re-order and delete any row at any time.

Comment: The output looks correct above...`D` has moved to position 3, in place of 'C'? why would `D` become position 2?

Comment: @christiandev, Actually, if i pass oldorder and neworder then it will work. But I am just passing oldorder and oldorder(+1/-1) in place of neworder which is casuing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update had a couple of issues...

```
UPDATE  @MyTable 
SET [Order] = (CASE 
                WHEN  [Order] = @OldOrder THEN     @NewOrder
                WHEN  @NewOrder > @OldOrder  THEN  [Order] - 1
                ELSE 
                    [Order] + 1 
            END)
WHERE   ([Order] BETWEEN @OldOrder AND @NewOrder OR [Order] BETWEEN @NewOrder AND @OldOrder)
```

1. `WHEN  3 > 4 THEN  [Order] - 1`
2. `WHERE   ([Order] BETWEEN 4 AND 3 OR [Order] BETWEEN 3 AND 4)`

You're only updating one record in this query, so the output is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your second WHEN condition never evaluates to true.
You assign `@NewOrder = @OldOrder - 1`, so `@NewOrder` is never larger than `@OldOrder`.